# Auto Lock Google Sheet Cells after Current Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an Attendance Sheet where I want to Lock the Edit Cell option for Previous Dates, future Dates. The user will be able to edit the cell on the current date and error to be shown if anyone updates it on the next day or elapsed time (Range: J2:AN4)

Spreadsheet Reference Link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13e4n6UIv2blZcVuFvuS2I95o5S_KUGKibfxsQeiRPa4/edit?usp=sharing

I am not much familiar with these options, If anyone can help that would be really great. Thanks!

Comment: By sharing spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). Instead, use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/). You can easily create a table using the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. However, the first row `A1:G1` must be a header row AND the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I want the range to get auto locked after a certain date so that attendance cannot be updated after the date elapsed.